# Compiling errors: Tk with X11 - help with dependencies

Tags: x11, makefile

Compiling errors: Tk with X11 - help with dependencies

I am trying to compile Tk into my code and I am having difficulty in getting X11 dependencies right in my Makefile. To include Tk I made the following change to my Makefile:

```
LIBS64 = \
    -ltk8.5 \
    -ltcl8.5
```

On compiling I got the following errors. I have edited it to reduce clutter:

```
...

: undefined reference to `XDrawLine'
<local>/libtk8.5.a(ttkElements.o)(.text+0x16b0): In function `SliderElementDraw':

...

: undefined reference to `XFillPolygon'
<local>/libtk8.5.a(ttkElements.o)(.text+0x1bbd): In function `TabElementDraw':

...

: undefined reference to `XFillRectangle'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

To get rid of this error I added -lX11 to my Makefile:

```
LIBS64 = \
    -ltk8.5 \
    -ltcl8.5 \
    -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 \
    -lX11
```

On compiling I got the following errors. I have edited it to reduce clutter:

```
: undefined reference to `FcPatternAddInteger'
<local>/libtk8.5.a(tkUnixRFont.o)(.text+0xe39): In function `TkpGetNativeFont':

: undefined reference to `XftXlfdParse'
<local>/libtk8.5.a(tkUnixRFont.o)(.text+0xe6c): In function `TkpGetNativeFont':

: undefined reference to `FcPatternDestroy'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So I tried adding more libraries but I seem stuck with compilation errors.

My last Makefile looked like this:

```
LIBS64 = \
    -ltk8.5 \
    -ltcl8.5 \
    -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 \
    -lXft \
    -lXss \
    -lX11 \
    -lICE \
    -lSM
```

I can't figure out what dependencies and the libraries that needs to included to get it compiled. I would be much obliged if some one can help me compile this.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious possibility here is that you are missing the development packages eg. the headers for tcl/tk, which usually look like tcl8.5-dev or tk8.5-dev, and if that is the case, then probably other development packages besides. What operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using Linux on a 64 bit Intel x86 machine. By headers do you mean #include<tk.h> ?

Comment: Which Linux distribution? Well, you need to include headers, of course, but I meant you need the headers installed in the first place. The dev packages include header files.

Comment: I am using                                                           % cat /etc/*-release
CentOS release 4.6 (Final)

Comment: My tcl8.5 tk8.5 are actually installed in <local> directory not /usr/lib. I have edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: I don't use CentOS, which is a RH derivative. In any case, check whether header files are installed. You are looking for packages that start with tk-devel and tcl-devel. rpm -qa | less gives a list of all packages. That's probably not the best command to use here, sorry.

Comment: Is there some reason you are not using the system one?

Comment: The system ones have 8.4 and we need 8.5 so I am using the local directory. I will ask my admin to upgrade my system tcl/tk. Thanks for your help.